# Simple TCP Client

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

I'm trying to implement simple TCP Client in Haskell. But it gets closed as soon as it connects. I don't know what is causing it to close. How could I make it so that it would print lines from server into `stdout` and send lines from `stdin` to server forever until `stdin` receives line ":quit"?

```
import Control.Monad (forever)
import Network (withSocketsDo, PortID(..), connectTo)
import System.IO
import Control.Concurrent (forkFinally)
import Control.Concurrent.Async (race)

main :: IO ()
main = withSocketsDo $ do
  -- connect to my local tcp server
  handle <- connectTo "192.168.137.1" (PortNumber 44444)
  -- should close the connection using handle after everything is done
  _ <- forkFinally (talk handle) (\_ -> hClose handle)
  return ()

talk :: Handle -> IO ()
talk handle = do
    hSetNewlineMode handle universalNewlineMode
    hSetBuffering handle LineBuffering
    -- if either one of them terminates, other one will get terminated
    _ <- race (interactWithServer handle) (interactWithUser handle)
    return ()

interactWithServer :: Handle -> IO ()
interactWithServer handle = forever $ do
  line <- hGetLine handle
  print line          -- print a line that came from server into stdout

interactWithUser :: Handle -> IO ()
interactWithUser handle = do
  line <- getLine
  case line of
    ":quit" -> return ()            -- stop loop if user input is :quit
    _ -> do hPutStrLn handle line
            interactWithUser handle -- send, then continue looping
```

Comment: In GHC, the whole program quits once the main thread does, even if there are other threads still running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [Ørjan Johansen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1088108/%C3%98rjan-johansen)'s help I figured it out. `forkFinally` was creating a thread then after that main thread was getting closed. That line was meant to wait until `talk` finished and then close the connection. It had to be (also shortened it)

```
main :: IO ()
main = withSocketsDo $ do
  handle <- connectTo "192.168.137.1" (PortNumber 44444)
  talk handle `finally` hClose handle

talk :: Handle -> IO ()
talk handle = do
    hSetNewlineMode handle universalNewlineMode
    hSetBuffering handle LineBuffering
    _ <- race fromServer toServer
    return ()
  where
    fromServer = forever $ do
      line <- hGetLine handle
      print line
    toServer = do
      line <- getLine
      case line of
-- server accepts /quit as disconnect command so better send it to the server 
        ":quit" -> do hPutStrLn handle "/quit"; return "Quit"
        _ ->  do hPutStrLn handle line; toServer
```

I hope this code is safe :D